# How to get rotation coordinates of point $(x',y')$ in terms of $(x,y)$

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given that we have $x=x' \cos \theta - y' \sin \theta $ and $y=x' \sin \theta +y' \cos \theta $ ,how can I express $x',y'$ in terms of $x,y$ and $a$ ?

I've browsed through the site to seek for some help but I've found that most of the questions involving rotation of coordinates involve the knowledge of matrices or vectors which I haven't yet studied.

Can you guys help me solve the problem  without the use of matrices,or vectors or some other  too advanced technique (for my level) ?

I've not been able to make any usefull attempt as I haven't clear in my mind how to get started.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $\cos(\theta)$ and the second by $\sin(\theta)$.  Then add the two equations and solve for $x'$.  You can find $y'$ similarly.

Comment: That was pretty clever. Thank you @Bye world